# Handling unknown words when making NER Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word2vec, named-entity-recognition

I'm working on my custom Named Entity Recognition model that I'm making in Python's Keras lib. I have read that I should enumerate all words that are appearing, so that I get vectorized sequences. I have done that like this:

```
word2idx = {w: i + 1 for i, w in enumerate(words)}
label2idx = {t: i for i, t in enumerate(labels)}

# CREATING FEATURES(X) AND RESULTS(Y)
max_len = 50 
num_words = len(num_words) #number of unique words in dataset
X = [[word2idx[w[0]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=num_words-1)

y = [[label2idx[w[1]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=y, padding="post", value=label2idx["O"])
y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=num_labels) for i in y]
```

This is my final model:

```
input_word = Input(shape=(max_len,))

model = Embedding(input_dim = num_words, output_dim = 50, input_length = max_len)(input_word)
model = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(model)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 5, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout = 0.1))(model)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_labels, activation = "softmax"))(model)

model = Model(input_word, out)
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 30)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 30, 50)            2187550   
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d (SpatialDr (None, 30, 50)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 30, 10)            2240      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 30, 11)            121       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,189,911  #LOOK AD THIS NUMBER
Trainable params: 2,189,911
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My accuracy is 98% and loss is 0.07. I like those results, but I have problem with making the prediction, because of the missing words. For example:

```
text = "I live in the Ohio and my name is Alex Wright and I work in AvcCC LTD"
text = text.split()
text = [word2idx[w] for w in text]

text = np.array(text)
print(text)
text=text.reshape(1,text.shape[0])

max_len = 50
text = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=text, padding="post", value=num_words-1)
print('PREDICTION')
res = model.predict(text).argmax(axis=-1)[0]
print(res)
```

ERROR:

```
KeyError: 'AvcCC'
```

In my dataset, and vocab there are no word 'AvcCC', how to handle that?

I want to use that code/model in production. Since my word2idx contains only words that were in starting data, how can I handle words that are not in my word2idx vocabulary? For example, its not possible for my word2idx vocabulary have all names and last names that exists, or all cities/locations, all company names, slang words etc.

My vocabulary had around 40k enumerated words (thats the number of unique words in my dataset). Then, I have enriched it with more than 100k other words. (I have made a web crawler that crawled different types of news articles). So now, my vocab has around 140k words. Now, instead of enumerating unique words from dataset, I'm loading my new word2idx/vocabulary.

```
word2idx = open('english-vocab.json')
word2idx = json.load(word2idx)

max_len = 50 
num_words = len(num_words) #number of unique words in dataset
X = [[word2idx[w[0]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=num_words-1)

y = [[label2idx[w[1]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=y, padding="post", value=label2idx["O"])
y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=num_labels) for i in y]
```

Accuracy and loss remained the same, but my model became much more slower because of the Total params (I can not use num_words anymore because it shows error, I need to use `len(word2idx)`)

```
input_word = Input(shape=(max_len,))

model = Embedding(input_dim = len(word2idx), output_dim = 50, input_length = max_len)(input_word)
model = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(model)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 5, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout = 0.1))(model)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_labels, activation = "softmax"))(model)

model = Model(input_word, out)
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 30)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 30, 50)            5596600   
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_1 (Spatial (None, 30, 50)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 30, 10)            2240      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 30, 11)            121       
=================================================================
Total params: 7,598,961 # MUCH BIGGER NUMBER
Trainable params: 5,598,961
Non-trainable params: 0
```

With creating my own word2idx I wanted to handle missing words in vocab, but only thing I did is that I slowed down training of my model.

How can I handle this kind of problem? How to handle missing/non-existing/unknown words ?

Comment: reserve a special token to map unknow words

Comment: ... unrelated:  `word2idx = {w: i + 1 for i, w in enumerate(words)}` ==>   `word2idx = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(words, 1)}`  simply start enumerating on 1 instead of 0 ...

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it?
Also, should I use my "custom made" word2idx or should I use the one thats made with dataset that I have?

Comment: @PatrickArtner So, it should start with 1, why is that?

Comment: @taga Dont ask me - YOU enumerate your "words" and add on the index all the time.

Comment: `text = [word2idx[w] for w in text]`  => `text = [word2idx.get(w, "UNKNOWN_WORD") for w in text]` would omit the key error - all unknown words would be replaced by  "UNKNOWN_WORD" wich you can add as new label or you can do  `text = [word2idx[w] for w in text if w in word2idx]` to eliminate all unknown words alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning it in the answer section of what Patrick has mentioned in the comment section for the benefit of the community also one more method to handle "OOV".

> text = [word2idx[w] for w in text] => text = [word2idx.get(w,
> "UNKNOWN_WORD") for w in text]
> would omit the key error - all unknown
> words would be replaced by "UNKNOWN_WORD" wich you can add as new
> label or you can do text = [word2idx[w] for w in text if w in
> word2idx] to eliminate all unknown words alltogether.

Below is the illustration for 300 dimension embedding matrix from the loaded pretrained embedding vectors. The below matrix will return all zero matrix for the out of vocabulary words.

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocabulary_size,300))
for word,index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  if index > vocabulary_size -1:
    break
  else:
      if word in index2word:
        embedding_matrix[index] = pretrained_model[word]
      else:
        pass
```